# Why is aligment icons menubar VisualEditor incorrect when using the Chameleon skin?

Tags: css, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, visual-editor

We've a problem with alignment of the VE menubar icons when using the Chameleon-skin (both version 1.1.4 and 1.2). Icons Undo, Redo, Link, Special character and Help are aligned incorrectly:

[image]

When using Vector-skin alignment is okay.

Anybody any suggestions?

Something to do with CSS I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved in version 1.3: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Szfhd5xgvuh66ggx